# How to add Ion Auth Login form in sidebar?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a blog application that I want a login form in a sidebar. I use Ion Auth library. How do I do that?

I have this in my sidebar view:

```
<?php echo form_open("blog/login");?>

  <p>
    <input type="text" name="identity">Username:</>         
  </p>      
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="password">Password:</>      
  </p>      
  <p>
   <label for="remember">Remember Me:</label>
      <?php echo form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE, 'id="remember"');?>
 </p>
  <p><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');?></p>      
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

But when I click "Login" it goes to different page. I want login function in my blog controller to work behind and staying in home page.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Please provide additional details of what is happening, in which controller is this sidebar view, what page does it redirect to, etc,

Comment: Hi @Slave! Sidebar view is in blog controller called login function. I want form proceed without it having related to url ex(when i click login button url is going 'blog/login'. I want login function to work behind

Comment: Probably not related to the actual problem, but `</>` is not a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without looking at the code, but I'm guessing that you could pass a hidden field in the form with the current URL.

Then, in the blog/login method, after you login the user, you can redirect to the URL received in the hidden field, instead of redirecting to base_url().